# multiple if statements

Tags: php, loop

Am I ok to use multiple if statements like the following, or is there a better more efficient method?

```
while ( $actionType_query->have_posts() )
{
        $actionType_query->the_post();

        if (has_term('NBS_CONS', 'broad_type_nbs' ) && has_term('NBS_AGF', 'ecosystem_nbs')) {
          $cons_a++;
        }
        if (has_term('NBS_CONS', 'broad_type_nbs' ) && has_term('NBS_CMA', 'ecosystem_nbs')) {
          $cons_b++;
        }
        if (has_term('NBS_CONS', 'broad_type_nbs' ) && has_term('NBS_FOR', 'ecosystem_nbs')) {
          $cons_c++;
        }
        if (has_term('NBS_CONS', 'broad_type_nbs' ) && has_term('NBS_GRA', 'ecosystem_nbs')) {
          $cons_d++;

        }
        if (has_term('NBS_CONS', 'broad_type_nbs' ) && has_term('NBS_MON', 'ecosystem_nbs')) {
          $cons_e++;

        }
        if (has_term('NBS_CONS', 'broad_type_nbs' ) && has_term('NBS_RIV', 'ecosystem_nbs')) {
          $cons_f++;
        }

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this working well? Or do you want to use 'else if' and 'else' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your `if` statements have the same `has_term('NBS_CONS', 'broad_type_nbs' )` function. This could be put in a variable for reuse instead.

& Your argument for each `if` statement is actually very consistent, so much so you could probably reduce it by just putting your varying data in an array, loop though, and use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
while ( $actionType_query->have_posts() ) {
    $actionType_query->the_post();
    $data = [
        'a' => 'AGF',
        'b' => 'CMA',
        'c' => 'FOR',
        'd' => 'GRA',
        'e' => 'MON',
        'f' => 'RIV',
    ];
    $broad_type_nbs = has_term('NBS_CONS', 'broad_type_nbs' );
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        if ($broad_type_nbs && has_term('NBS_'.$v, 'ecosystem_nbs')) {
            ${'cons_'.$k}++;
        }
    }
}
```